# Cerrar sesión de spring security una vez que se cierra la pestaña

Tags: spring-security

Estoy trabajando con las sesiones de spring security y quisiera que cuando el usuario cierre la ventana (o pestaña) se anule la session del sprint security.

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido, no es buena idea. El cliente debe enviar la petición al servidor para decir "cierra sesión" por evento del usuario o el servidor invalida la sesión puesto que pasó el tiempo base para mantener la sesión viva. Podrías intentarlo por JS pero no es muy seguro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente con Javascript:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(){
        //Aqui hacer un http get a tu controller de logout
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", "/logout", false ); // false para asincrona
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el cliente tiene abierta más de una pestaña y trabaja con la aplicación? ¿Al cerrar una pestaña, se cerrará la sesión en todo el navegador?

Comment: Si, tienes razón, pero creo que es un caso que tendría que considerar el OP.